# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringMVCApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC and i am trying to run my first app but I am getting the following error. I am not sure what is wrong with my code but I get the following error:

```
 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringMVCApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCApp</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Here is my dispatcher file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.test"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value> 
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is my controller

```
package com.spring.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller

public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hellospring")
    public String printHello(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello spring...");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Here is my jsp file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

assuming **FirstSpringMVCApp** your application name and you have deployed your application in a server which is running on the port 8080 then you should use the following URL to run the application

```
localhost:8080/FirstSpringMVCApp/hellospring
```

Comment: Not exactly *to run the application*, but rather *to hit the controller* as your `@RequestMapping` declares the url (relative to context) `/hellospring`.

Answer (score 0):

resolved it:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String gotoIndex(){
return "index";
}
```

and its work!!

Comment: You should consider to explain your answer instead of only posting the code.